# Filter from custom data attribute array

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am stuck with  logic in this file, I would really appreciate some help.

the scenario - multiple filter in one page, one is working other isn't

What I need to achieve - make the problematic filter work, the context is after making it work there would also be combination in both filters.

Below is the complete file showing the issue.

Thanks In advance

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <style>
    .filter .nav-link {
      padding: 0.6rem 1rem;
    }

    .nav-pills .nav-link {
      border-radius: 1.25rem;
      font-weight: 500;
      letter-spacing: 1.3px;
    }

    .filter .nav-pills .nav-link.active,
    .nav-pills .show>.nav-link {
      color: #212529;
      background-color: #f7f7f7;
    }

    @keyframes zoom-in {
      0% {
        transform: scale(.1);
      }

      100% {
        transform: none;
      }
    }

    @keyframes rotate-right {
      0% {
        transform: translate(-100%) rotate(-100deg);
      }

      100% {
        transform: none;
      }
    }

    .is-animated {
      animation: .6s zoom-in;
      /*animation: .6s rotate-right; */
    }

    .container-fluid {
      padding-top: 2em;
    }

    i.bi.bi-emoji-smile-fill {
      color: #1faa00;
    }

    i.bi.bi-emoji-frown-fill {
      color: #dd2c00;
    }

    i.bi.bi-emoji-neutral-fill {
      color: #9e9e9e;
    }

    i.bi.bi-emoji-smile-upside-down-fill {
      color: #4d2c91;
    }

    .head-info {
      display: flex;
    }

    .ch-inner a {
      text-decoration: none;
      line-height: 20px;
      vertical-align: bottom;
      padding: 0 1em;
      font-weight: 500;
      color: #277cfa;
    }

    .adtn-info span.badge.bg-secondary {
      margin-right: 1em;
    }

    .adtn-info a {
      line-height: 1.3em;
    }

    span.badge.badge-custom {
      color: #6c757d;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      margin: 0 0.5em;
    }
    .card-add-tag .form-control {
      display: inline;
      width:10%;
      border:none;
    }
    .filter li.list-group-item {
    cursor: pointer;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2 filter">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#" data-filter="all">All</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-filter="positive">Positive</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-filter="neutral">Neutral</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-filter="negative">Negative</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-filter="mixed">Mixed</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <p>Filter by Tag:</p>
        <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
        <br>
        <ul class="list-group" id="myList">
          <li class="list-group-item">
          <a href="#" data-tag="a">  a</a>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <a href="#" data-tag="b">  b</a>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <a href="#" data-tag="c">  c</a>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <a href="#" data-tag="d">  d</a>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <a href="#" data-tag="e">  e</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-10">
        <div class="row comments">
          <div class="col-12 mb-4" data-category="positive">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">

                <div class="row ">
                  <div class="col-8 ch-inner">

                    <div class="head-info">
                      <h3><i class="bi bi-emoji-smile-fill"></i></h3>
                      <p><a href="">Harry Potter</a></p>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 adtn-info">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                      <span class="badge bg-secondary">1 week ago</span>
                      <a href="#"><span class="badge bg-secondary">3<i class="bi bi-list"></i></span></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                <div class="row card-add-tag">
                  <div class="col-12 ">
                  <hr>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom" data-commentTag="">Tag 1</span>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom">Tag 2</span>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom">Tag 3</span>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom">Tag 4</span>
                  <input class="form-control" list="datalistOptions" id="tagDataList" placeholder="Add Tag...">
                  <datalist id="datalistOptions">
                    <option value="San Francisco">
                    <option value="New York">
                    <option value="Seattle">
                    <option value="Los Angeles">
                    <option value="Chicago">
                  </datalist>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>



            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col-12 mb-4" data-category="positive">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-8 ch-inner">

                    <div class="head-info">
                      <h3><i class="bi bi-emoji-smile-fill"></i></h3>
                      <p><a href="">Harry Potter</a></p>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 adtn-info">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                      <span class="badge bg-secondary">1 week ago</span>
                      <a href="#"><span class="badge bg-secondary">3<i class="bi bi-list"></i></span></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <div class="row card-add-tag">
                  <div class="col-12">
                  <hr>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom" data-commentTag="a">Tag 1</span>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom">Tag 2</span>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom">Tag 3</span>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom">Tag 4</span>
                  <input class="form-control" list="datalistOptions" id="tagDataList" placeholder="Add Tag...">
                  <datalist id="datalistOptions">
                    <option value="San Francisco">
                    <option value="New York">
                    <option value="Seattle">
                    <option value="Los Angeles">
                    <option value="Chicago">
                  </datalist>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 mb-4" data-category="negative">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-8 ch-inner">
                    <div class="head-info">
                      <h3><i class="bi bi-emoji-frown-fill"></i></h3>
                      <p><a href="">Harry Potter</a></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 adtn-info">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                      <span class="badge bg-secondary">1 week ago</span>
                      <a href="#"><span class="badge bg-secondary">3<i class="bi bi-list"></i></span></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>



              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                <div class="row card-add-tag">
                  <div class="col-12">
                  <hr>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom" data-commentTag="">Tag 1</span>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom">Tag 2</span>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom">Tag 3</span>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom">Tag 4</span>
                  <input class="form-control" list="datalistOptions" id="tagDataList" placeholder="Add Tag...">
                  <datalist id="datalistOptions">
                    <option value="San Francisco">
                    <option value="New York">
                    <option value="Seattle">
                    <option value="Los Angeles">
                    <option value="Chicago">
                  </datalist>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 mb-4" data-category="neutral">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-8 ch-inner">
                    <div class="head-info">
                      <h3><i class="bi bi-emoji-neutral-fill"></i></h3>
                      <p><a href="">Harry Potter</a></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 adtn-info">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                      <span class="badge bg-secondary">1 week ago</span>
                      <a href="#"><span class="badge bg-secondary">3<i class="bi bi-list"></i></span></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                <div class="row card-add-tag">
                  <div class="col-12">
                  <hr>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom" data-commentTag="a">Tag 1</span>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom">Tag 2</span>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom">Tag 3</span>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom">Tag 4</span>
                  <input class="form-control" list="datalistOptions" id="tagDataList" placeholder="Add Tag...">
                  <datalist id="datalistOptions">
                    <option value="San Francisco">
                    <option value="New York">
                    <option value="Seattle">
                    <option value="Los Angeles">
                    <option value="Chicago">
                  </datalist>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-12 mb-4" data-category="mixed">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-8 ch-inner">
                    <div class="head-info">
                      <h3><i class="bi bi-emoji-smile-upside-down-fill"></i></h3>
                      <p><a href="">Harry Potter</a></p>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 adtn-info">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                      <span class="badge bg-secondary">1 week ago</span>
                      <a href="#"><span class="badge bg-secondary">3<i class="bi bi-list"></i></span></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                <div class="row card-add-tag">
                  <div class="col-12">
                  <hr>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom" data-commentTag="a">Tag 1</span>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom">Tag 2</span>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom">Tag 3</span>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom">Tag 4</span>
                  <input class="form-control" list="datalistOptions" id="tagDataList" placeholder="Add Tag...">
                  <datalist id="datalistOptions">
                    <option value="San Francisco">
                    <option value="New York">
                    <option value="Seattle">
                    <option value="Los Angeles">
                    <option value="Chicago">
                  </datalist>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-12 mb-4" data-category="neutral">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-8 ch-inner">
                    <div class="head-info">
                      <h3><i class="bi bi-emoji-neutral-fill"></i></h3>
                      <p><a href="">Harry Potter</a></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4 adtn-info">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                      <span class="badge bg-secondary">1 week ago</span>
                      <a href="#"><span class="badge bg-secondary">3<i class="bi bi-list"></i></span></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>

                <div class="row card-add-tag">
                  <div class="col-12">
                  <hr>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom" data-commentTag="a">Tag 1</span>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom" data-commentTag="b">Tag 2</span>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom">Tag 3</span>
                  <span class="badge badge-custom">Tag 4</span>
                  <input class="form-control" list="datalistOptions" id="tagDataList" placeholder="Add Tag...">
                  <datalist id="datalistOptions">
                    <option value="San Francisco">
                    <option value="New York">
                    <option value="Seattle">
                    <option value="Los Angeles">
                    <option value="Chicago">
                  </datalist>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

      $("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#myList li").filter(function () {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      });
    });

    
    (function ($) {
      var $filters = $('.filter [data-filter]'),
        $comments = $('.comments [data-category]'),
        $tagList = $('.filter [data-tag]'),
        $tagCat = $('.comments [data-commentTag]');

        
       // console.log($tagList);
        
        
        

      $filters.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        
        $filters.removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');

        var $filterCat = $this.attr('data-filter');
        //console.log($filterCat);

        if ($filterCat == 'all') {
          $comments.removeClass('is-animated')
            .fadeOut().promise().done(function () {
              $comments.addClass('is-animated').fadeIn();
            });
        } else {
          $comments.removeClass('is-animated')
            .fadeOut().promise().done(function () {
              $comments.filter('[data-category = "' + $filterCat + '"]')
                .addClass('is-animated').fadeIn();
            });
        }
      });
      
    })(jQuery);


    (function ($) {
      var $comments = $('.comments [data-category]'),
        $tagList = $('.filter [data-tag]'),
        $tagCat = $('.comments [data-commentTag]');

      //console.log($tagCat);
    $tagList.on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        //  console.log($ct);
        
        

        $tagList.removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');

         var $filterTag = $this.attr('data-tag');
         
         //console.log($filterTag);
         //console.log($tagCat);
        
         $( ".badge-custom" ).each(function( index ) {
          $ct = $(this).attr('data-commenttag');
          if($ct !== undefined){
            var arr = [];
            arr.push($ct);
            //  console.log(arr);
          }
   
          $.each(arr, function(index, value){
            var x = value;
            //console.log(x);
            //console.log($filterTag);

            if ($filterTag == x) {
              // console.log("yes");
                   $comments.removeClass('is-animated')
                     .fadeOut().promise().done(function () {
                       $comments.filter('[data-commenttag = "' + x + '"]').addClass('is-animated').fadeIn();
                       //console.log(o);
                       //console.log(x);
                     });
                }
          });
          
        }); 

      });
  })(jQuery);


  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-eMNCOe7tC1doHpGoWe/6oMVemdAVTMs2xqW4mwXrXsW0L84Iytr2wi5v2QjrP/xp"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-cn7l7gDp0eyniUwwAZgrzD06kc/tftFf19TOAs2zVinnD/C7E91j9yyk5//jjpt/"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You have not provided details on an error message or what you have tried to solve the issue. You'll usually have more luck getting quality answers when you attempt to describe both the problem and what you've tried to solve it in more detail. Pasting code snippets and saying "it doesn't work" won't lead to much help in most instances.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @fjc  Thank you for your response, I've updated my question. hope it gives a clear understanding of the scenario now.

Comment: can you specify which filter not working ?

Comment: Filter by tag one isn't working